# Deference between xymon-client and xymon-client~

Tags: 14.04

Why do I see *xymon-client* and *xymon-client~*?

I don't know what the `~` character means.  Could tell me, please?

And how to remove-fix it? That is, if it's possible.

Thank you all.

Comment: the later one is the backup of the same file

Comment: whenever you edit a text file then i guess os keeps a backup of the same file with '~' at the end. i see lots of those files in my computer.you can simply delete it.

Comment: And how to remove-fix it? if its possible.

Comment: you can just simply delete the file

Comment: rm name_of_the_file

Answer (score 0):

The `~` sign at the end of your file is simply signalling that it is a backup of the file that has the same name without the `~`.

Editors like `gedit` frequently make a backup copy of the files they edit before saving.  It prevents a total loss of data in case of a failed save.

You can delete the file, but it will appear again next time you save with whatever editor is leaving it.  With most editors, you can tell it in preferences not to create backups when saving.